# Google Analytics Content Experiments dynamic page with different parameter redirects to default

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-experiments

I have a site with only one page named `products.php` and I show different categories (around 50 of them) with a query string like `products.php?category=books`. Now, I've set the content experiments for the url `products.php?category=books` and all worked fine, except the fact that when I try to access any other category I get redirected to the aforementioned `books` category. How can I get this working?

Ideally I would like to set a "dynamic" experiment which would work for every category, but I could live with if I could set up just one category and that all other wouldn't be redirecting to the `books` category. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple in the end actually: just set the Content Experiments with the original url `products.php` without the additional parameters, as they (if existing) will get propagated, as explained on [official google analytics support page](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2618450):

```
3. URL parameters in your variation pages

If you set URL parameters in your variation pages, then Experiments incorporates
them into what the visitor sees. Let’s say you set your experiment pages as:

Original page: www.example.com/a
Variation page: www.example.com/b?id=50
If visitors arrive with no URL parameters, then they see one of these two pages:

Original page: www.example.com/a
Variation page: www.example.com/b?id=50
If visitors arrive with URL parameters that conflict, then the URL parameters you
supplied during the experiment setup override the URL parameters that visitors
arrive with.

For example, if the visitor clicks a link to www.example.com/a?id=1, the visitor sees one of these two pages:

Original page: www.example.com/a?id=1
Variation page: www.example.com/b?id=50
If visitors arrive with URL parameters that don’t conflict, then the URL parameters are
appended to the page URL. For example, if the visitor clicks a link to
www.example.com/a?cat=1, then the visitor sees one of these two pages:

Original page: www.example.com/a?cat=1
Variation page: www.example.com/b?id=50&cat=1
```